# PHP: Radiobutton with checked not working

Tags: php, radio-button, checked

I have a radiobutton but then its not working when I click the submit button.. The submit button will just reload again the page of "weeks_process.php" [same page] but then the checked comman in may code is not working..

Here's my code below:

```
$radio = mysql_query("SELECT fldNetname FROM tbldata WHERE fldWeek = '$get_week' GROUP BY fldNetname ORDER BY fldNetname");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($radio))
{
echo "<div><input type='radio' name='playRadio[]' class='chk_boxes1' value='" . $row['fldNetname']."' " .($_POST['playRadio[]'] == $row['fldNetname'] ? 'checked' : '') . " >";

echo $row['fldNetname'];"</div>";
}
```

thanks

Comment: `[]` is for checkboxes where multiple values can be selected ;)

Comment: Change all `playRadio[]` to just `playRadio`. Radio buttons are unique choices, as opposed to checkboxes which can be set in an array as a multiple choice.

Comment: @Fred..thanks for the help also

Answer (score 2):

The name of your radios must not be an array: you need to use the same name for all the radios, and you will get a single value in PHP holding the value the user selected.